# How to use QgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions Class

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am writing plugin, that connects to postgresql and loads some layers.
I am trying to add my own `QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider` for some groups with my layers but to let old menus for all other layers and groups.

I can not understand how to use `QgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions`. Can anybody show some example?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of adding a menu with a `Zoom to Layer` action to a layer tree view. Tested with PyQt 5.12 and PyQgis 3.18

layers_tree_menu.py :

```
class MyMenuProvider(QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider):
    def __init__(self, layer_tree_view, map_canvas):
        '''Initializes the provider and the factory class'''
        super(MyMenuProvider, self).__init__()
        self._view = layer_tree_view
        self._canvas = map_canvas
        self._default_actions_factory = QgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions(self._view)

    def createContextMenu(self):
        # If user didn't right-click on a layer in the tree view
        if not self._view.currentLayer(): 
            return None
        m = QMenu()
        self._zoom_to_layer = self._default_actions_factory.actionZoomToLayers(self._canvas)
        m.addAction(self._zoom_to_layer)
        return m
```

main_window.py :

```
# Assuming we already have a working QgsLayerTreeView instance called 'layers_tree_view',
# as well as a working QgsMapCanvas instance called 'map_canvas'

from layers_tree_menu import MyMenuProvider

...

layers_tree_menu_provider = MyMenuProvider(layers_tree_view, map_canvas)
layers_tree_view.setMenuProvider(layers_tree_menu_provider)
```

With this code, whenever the user right-clicks on a layer in the layer tree view, a menu with a `Zoom to Layer` action would show up. Clicking this action would cause the map canvas to zoom to the extent of the clicked layer.

Comment: Nice example, thank you! Side note: For QGIS 3.16 or older one must use `actionZoomToLayer`, since `actionZoomToLayers` is not available there